# Is there a standardized way to incorporate domain knowledge into population based optimization algorithm?

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithms

In metaheuristics, domain knowledge can be used to generate initial population to improve convergence rates in population based algorithms. (e.g. a good example is in [this paper](http://ascelibrary.org/doi/abs/10.1061/(ASCE)WR.1943-5452.0000649))

Is it possible to use domain knowledge to improve the population generation process? For instance, is it legit to use domain knowledge to refine the perturbations to generate new population, or modifying the the acceptance probability of each candidate? Is there any established methods for doing this?

(Assuming the domain knowledge is ambiguous and imprecise, e.g. we know the optimal solution is more more likely to be within certain range, but not sure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. There are no real rules behind metaheuristics aside from "do it if it works".

I don't know that there are really general methods for doing it, as it's by definition problem dependent. But I would absolutely use whatever knowledge I had available. For instance, if I needed to solve a knapsack problem with a GA, where I knew that the data for my instances involved sparse knapsacks (i.e., optimal solutions would contain a few relatively heavy items and many more unselected ones), I would totally bias my initial population generation to favor producing individuals with far more zero bits than ones.

At a certain point, you can run into diversity problems if your initialization is too deterministic, but there again, the answer is basically to do what works the best. There's no obvious way to know when you have "enough", and it will certainly depend on the characteristics of the fitness function, your other variation operators, etc.